# How to fix "request for member ‘rank’ in something not a structure or union"?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dereference

I'm trying to create an array of structure in C and I want to initialize it.
But I get this error and I don't know how to fix it.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    struct argnum{
        int rank;
        char fileNamne[10];
    };

    void** argtab= malloc(sizeof(struct argnum)*(argc-1));

    for(int i=0; i<argc-1; i++){
        argtab[i]->rank=i;
        argtab[i]->filename=argv[i];
    }
}
```

> ```
> Exercise2.c: In function ‘main’:
> Exercise2.c:22:18: error: request for member ‘rank’ in something not a structure or union
>      argtab[i]->rank=i;
>               ^
> Exercise2.c:23:18: error: request for member ‘filename’ in something not a structure or union
>      argtab[i]->filename=argv[i];
>               ^
> ```

Comment: `void *` is not a structure type; it has never has any members.  You'd need an array of `struct argnum *` to use the `argtab[i]->filename` notation; an array of `struct argnum` would be more sensible, and you'd use `argnum[i].filename`.  You also should fix `fileNamne` and `filename` for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

If the type of `argtab` is `void **`, then the type of `argtab[i]` is `void *`, which is not a pointer to a struct or union type.

Note that changing the type of `argtab` from `void **` to `struct argnum**` isn’t good enough, because you’ll have to allocate each `argtab[i]` *in addition* to allocating `argtab`.

You’d probably be better off allocating `argtab` as

```
struct argnum *argtab = malloc( sizeof *argtab * (argc - 1));
```

and then use `.` instead of `->` to access each member:

```
argtab[i].rank = i;
```

since each `argtab[i]` will be type `struct argnum`, not `struct argnum *`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void** argtab= malloc(sizeof(struct argnum)*(argc-1));
```

Why do you declare `argtab` as a `void **`? If you need an array of structures, you have to declare it this way:

```
struct argnum *argtab = malloc(sizeof(struct argnum) * (argc-1));
```

Now the compiler is aware that `argtab` is not just a "bag of bytes" but a structure whose fields it knows.

Also it is unusual, though allowed, to declare a structure inside a function.

Comment: If you use that type for `argtab`, then the access to the members needs to be `argtab[i].rank` (dot instead of arrow).  If you allocate an array of pointers to `struct argtab` (`struct argnum **argtsb`), then you also have allocate the memory for the elements of the array, of course.